# Отправка запроса curl

Tags: php, curl

```
$url_page = "ссылка на страницу";
$param = "список параметров";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url_page);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
curl_exec($curl);
```

Данный код не отрабатывает, но при использовании программы soupUI и установке Post QueryString все отрабатывает. Не могу понять в чем проблема

Comment: а что у нас `$param`? массив? если да, попробуйте обертку `http_build_query($param)`

Comment: строка к примеру $param = "id1=1&id2=10&id3=1";

Comment: можно тогда увидеть полный код? не понятно как вы получаете результат.

Comment: к сожелению часть по приемке находится на удаленном сервере куда я доступ не имею (но в soup UI отрабатывает в стандартных настройках с учетом если включена post query data и content type: application/json)

Comment: тогда сорри, помочь не могу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для content type: application/json передаются данные в JSON(вполне вероятно что сервер работает только с таким форматом):

```
$headers = array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
$param = '{"id1" : 1, "id2" : 10, "id3" : 1}';
$ch = curl_init($url_page);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$param);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```